# how to add a textbox to each header column of a Gridview and filter that column using the textbox?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, wpfdatagrid

i need to add a textbox to each column's header of a DataGrid and filter that column using this textbox? 
i used this post to add textbox to  column header but i don't know how to bind them to Viewmodel?
[Datagrid custom header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035082/datagrid-custom-header)

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom class, which will represent your filterable headers, then you can put additional collection of filterable headers into your view model, so you will expose two collections - one for actual data and one for headers binding and then bind it. Also you can check this : [WPF Datagrid binding custom column headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189671/wpf-datagrid-binding-custom-column-headers)